# .NET cross-platform alternative to Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.ShellFile

Tags: .net-core, cross-platform, nuget-package, windows-shell

I am moving an old library project from .NET Framework 4.7.1 to .NET 7/8. One of the goals is to make the libraries cross-platform rather than Windows-only. So far I have succeeded, but there's a last issue. My code uses the `ShellFile` type in the `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell` package to read file metadata, that is, the bits of information that you get when you look at the Details tab in the File Properties dialog box in Windows:

[image]

Unfortunately, this package requires that my library uses the `net7.0-windows` target framework rather than just `net7.0`.

Note that I am not aiming to read `.docx` details specifically, but those of any file. I am assuming that MacOS, Linux and other platforms have something similar to Windows in relation to storing and retrieving file metadata like Windows does.

Is there a cross-platform alternative to this? I would like a package that can read the basic metadata of files in the file system, such as their title or authors, while hiding the platform-specific details. Thanks.

Comment: You can read that information w/o any dependency on any 3rd party package (ie: just using C# and interop code), but this code will never be "cross platform" since the general way it's stored is Windows specific. Or are you just looking for a way to read .docx files metadata specifically?

Comment: @SimonMourier: Clarified in question, thanks.

Comment: Speaking for Windows, these properties that you see here are a mix of Windows storage (ex: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/ipropertysetstorage-ntfs-file-system-implementation) or file storage like images EXIF metadata, or old Office documents (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/compound-documents) or newer Office (OpenXML), etc but Windows (most of the time, depends on config) makes them appear as unified https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/property-system-overview I doubt there's anything cross platform

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I'm interested in the very basics, just the title and authors.

Comment: not an easy task, especially when no new packages, let alone any updates are around for about 10 years. If you got time, though, you may try implementing one yourself from sources of the old one: https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1/blob/master/source/WindowsAPICodePack/Shell/Common/ShellFile.cs

Comment: The best approach depends on the specific type of metadata you want to access and your desired level of portability.

Here's a general guideline:
_For basic properties like creation date and size_: Utilize built-in file system properties. (System.IO)
_For standardized metadata formats embedded in files_: Leverage XMP or ID3 tags.
_For more advanced or custom metadata_: Explore ExifTool, third-party libraries, or consider sidecar files with careful implementation.